# Trigger plugged in Portable Devices like iPhone

Tags: c#, windows

I'd like to store pictures from iPhone 5 (iOs7) to the client Computer Windows 7 x64.

Now, the problem is, I can't loop through the connected MassStorageDevices.
iPhones are recognized by Windows as Portable Devices and does not have a logical drive letter.

**So my Goal is:**

- Trigger a connected WindowsMediaDevice (eg. iPhone/iPad)
- Get the pictures of it. Or at least the path (eg.
  (\ApplesIphone\IMG...))

*Note: MassSotrageDevice trigger algorithm won't work*

I read this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505230/how-to-get-files-from-a-device-using-usb), asked four years ago. Is there any solution nearly after a half decade?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the https://mobiledevice.codeplex.com/ library. It's maybe not up-to-date but it will get you started.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look.